# Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency for Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have used these:

```
Install New Software ---> Add
```

Inside Add Repository write the Name:

- ADT (or, as you want)
- Location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

After loading some time you will get Developer Tools.

- Check Developer Tool
- Click Next
- Finish

But I get these error :

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. 
Software being installed: Android DDMS 23.0.7.2120684 
(com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.7.2120684) 
Software currently installed: Android DDMS 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 
(com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group
```

Can any body help me solution for this problem ?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are running Eclipse J2EE or Eclipse Java Developer.

This issue will be solved if you use Eclipse Java Developer tool.

Answer (score -2):

ADT was deprecated 8 months ago:

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html

you should consider moving to Android Studio.